# Find PDF of $Z = X + Y$ where $X$ and $Y$ are jointly continuous random variables.

Tags: probability-theory

I want to check my solution.

Let $X$ and $Y$ be jointly continuous random variables and $Z = X + Y$.

For some $z$, $X = z - Y$.

Thus

$F_Z(z) = Pr(Z < z) = Pr(X < z - Y)= \int_{-\infty}^\infty\int_{-\infty}^{z - y} f_{X,Y}(s, t)dsdt
= \int_{-\infty}^\infty\int_{-\infty}^{z - y} f_{X}(s)f_Y(t)dsdt
= \int_{-\infty}^\infty F_X(z-y)f_Y(t)dt 
= E[F_X(z-y)]$

Now, to get the PDF of $Z$,

$ f_Z(z) = {\partial F_Z(z) \over \partial z} = {\partial \over \partial z} \int_{-\infty}^\infty F_X(z-y)f_Y(t)dsdt$

Since $F_X(z-y)f_Y(t)$ is bounded, $ {\partial \over \partial z} \int_{-\infty}^\infty F_X(z-y)f_Y(t)dt = \int_{-\infty}^\infty {\partial \over \partial z}F_X(z-y)f_Y(t)dt $

Hence $f_Z(z) = \int_{-\infty}^\infty f_Z(z-y)f_Y(t)dt = E[f_Z(z-y)]$ , since  ${\partial \over \partial z}F_X(z-y) = f_Z(z-y)$

I just have calculated as I can, but I am not sure about the precision of each steps.

Answer (score 2):

There is a very common technique for doing this. Look up [convolution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convolution) of probability density functions and you will see how to do this. Also, you should look up [characteristic functions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Characteristic_function_%28probability_theory%29) for a potentially faster way.

Answer (score 1):

$$\begin{align}
f_{\small Z}(z) & =\dfrac{\mathrm d ~~}{\mathrm d z}F_{\small Z}(z)\\&=\dfrac{\mathsf d~~}{\mathrm d z}\iint_{s+t<z} f_{\small X,Y}(s,t)\,\mathrm d s\,\mathrm d t\\&=\dfrac{\mathsf d~~}{\mathrm d z}\int_\Bbb R\int_{-\infty}^{z-t} f_{\small X,Y}(s,t)\,\mathrm d s\,\mathrm d t\\&=\int_\Bbb R \left\lvert\dfrac{\partial (z-t)}{\partial z}\right\rvert f_{\small X,Y}(z-t, t)\,\mathrm d t\\&=\int_\Bbb R f_{\small X,Y}(z-t, t)\,\mathrm d t
\end{align}$$